# How to find row in SQL which got a specific unicode character

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

We have SQL report builder but we get a error: An error has occured during report processing (rsProcessingAborted).

If I check the ReportServerService log then I see this:

```
e ERROR: Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.RSException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> System.Text.EncoderFallbackException: Unable to translate Unicode character \uDB5D at index 389 to specified code page.
   at System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Char charUnknown, Int32 index)
   at System.Text.EncoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Char ch, Char*& chars)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS baseEncoder)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String chars)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.PersistenceBinaryWriter.Write(String str, Boolean writeObjType)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(Object obj, Boolean verify, Boolean assertOnInvalidType)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.TryWriteSerializable(Object obj)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.RecordField.Serialize(IntermediateFormatWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(IPersistable persistableObj, Boolean verify)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(IPersistable[] array)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.RecordRow.Serialize(IntermediateFormatWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.IntermediateFormatWriter.Write(IPersistable persistableObj, Boolean verify)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Persistence.ChunkManager.DataChunkWriter.WriteRecordRow(RecordRow recordRow)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.TablixProcessing.RuntimeOnDemandDataSet.ProcessRow(RecordRow row, Int32 rowNumber)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.ProcessRows()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.Process()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.RuntimeAtomicDataSet.ProcessConcurrent(Object threadSet)
```

Probably in a table there is a value with a strange character. Is it also possible to find the correct row which contains the unicode :uDB5D I tried:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OrderLines
  WHERE OrderLines.ItemDescription LIKE CONCAT('%',UNICODE(0xDB5D),'%')
```

but this did not give me any results..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50) = 0xDB5D 

SELECT @test
WHERE   @test like N'%巛%'
```

you can test where the 'offending' character is by converting it to binary:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50) = 0xDB5D 
SET @test = @test + N'test'
SELECT @test, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @test)
WHERE   @test like N'%巛%'
```

Results in:

```
+-------+------------------------+
| 巛test | 0xDB5D7400650073007400 |
+-------+------------------------+
```

So you can spot the `0xDB5D` at the start of the binary string.

Comment: What I do is I have report builder in which I have a start and end date, on one particular date I get the error of above. So there is data in the SQL which has special characters thats why I get this error, but I cant find the specifc row and column in SQL.

Comment: @YdB added a little test so you can see where the character is.

Comment: Nice. It seems that its not in the column orderlines. Is it also possible to track in which column I can find the unicode 0xDb5D?

Comment: I don't know enough about reporting services to say. Do you have many columns, can't you just test them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

The unicode conversion is wrong use NCHAR(0xDB5D) like so:

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(ItemDescription NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES (N'�')
SELECT * FROM @Orders WHERE ItemDescription LIKE CONCAT(N'%',NCHAR(0xDB5D),N'%')
```